# CGContextShowText to draw in center aligned

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-text

Trying to draw the text using CGContextShowText.How to make the text centered in the specific rect?

Note: drawInRect can do this job.I am asking particularly about CGContextShowText

Comment: Get the size of the text, subtract from size of rect, halve it, add to X origin of rect, draw there.

Comment: Thank you.thought about this one .so there is no definite method to set it like we set the font and other properties?

Comment: Well, what does the documentation say?

Comment: Draw `string', a string of `length' bytes, at the point `(x, y)',
specified in user space, in the context `c'. Each byte of the string is  mapped through the encoding vector of the current font to obtain the  glyph to display.

Comment: I mean, aren't there any functions of which the description mentions the possibility of specifying text alignment? If so, then you have to do the math yourself.

Comment: searched,I didnt see any ,thats why i asked :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `CGContextShowText` (Core Text would be better), you'll have to do the math yourself, i.e. figure out how big the text is, and subtract half of that from the x coordinate of your center point.

To determine the size of the text, you could set the text drawing mode to `kCGTextInvisible` (using `CGContextSetTextDrawingMode`), draw the text once, check how far the text position has moved (using `CGContextGetTextPosition` before and after drawing), and then draw the text again with a visible drawing mode at the correct location.